# How to convert CLOB data to VARCHAR2 before inserting to Oracle table using Kafka connect jdbc sink?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

U am using Confluent 3.3.0. I am working with Kafka jdbc sink connector to insert rows to my Oracle table. You may refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48224386/why-kafka-jdbc-connect-insert-data-as-blob-instead-of-varchar) question to understand my Java producer code and Kafka connect settings. Everything works fine, but values are getting inserted as CLOB. I have very simple records, say, 3 string attributes. So i am expecting the values to be inserted as VARCHAR2. From the [Confluent documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/3.3.0/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/sink_connector.html), it is clear that, for Oracle, string is mapped to CLOB. I want to customize the mapping. Is there any way to convert it into VARCHAR2 and insert it?

Thank you.

Comment: don't know the product, but can you set a size limit to the strings to be mapped? Varchar2 has a maximum length of 2000 characters, mapping frameworks may automatically map Strings to CLOB if they aren't restricted to that limit.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
cast(to_char(your_clob_column) as varchar2(4000))
```

Comment: Could you kindly tell me where i should implement this?

Comment: you can use this which your select statement to clob column. I mean : select *****this****** from a,b,c .